# Django numerical RangeField (for SQLite)

Tags: python, django, django-models

After reading the [docs for custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-model-fields/) of Django 5.0 I'm not sure if or how it's possible to create a ModelField that resembles a range between two numerical (integer) values, since I can only serialize into a single db_column, not into two (min of range, max of range column).

Am I wrong? Is there a possibility I don't see?

I know for PostgreSQL there are different [RangeFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields) available.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the similar snippet here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3016/

You will get a idea how you achieve your use case using Custom Integer Field

Comment: I don't see how this field will save a two values, it just adds min/max validation